# Proof of divergence of $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/11 +....$

Tags: prime-numbers, divergent-series

What is an elementary proof to the fact that $\frac{1}{p_1} + \frac{1}{p_2} + \frac{1}{p_3} + \dots$ diverges. ($p_i$ denotes the $i$th prime.)

Comment: Have you seen Erdos's proof?

Comment: Searching for [prime series diverges site:math.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=prime+series+diverges+site:math.stackexchange.com) gives several similar questions:
[Does the sum of reciprocals of primes converge?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/),
[Sum of reciprocal prime numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/),
[Need help understanding Erdős' proof about divergence of $\sum\frac1p$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407362/),
[Clarkson's Proof of the Divergence of Reciprocal of Primes](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361308/).

Comment: There is also a Wikipedia article [Divergence of the sum of the reciprocals of the primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) containing several proofs.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
 \log \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}\right) & {} = \log \left( \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}\right)
  = \sum_p \log \left( \frac{1}{1-p^{-1}}\right) = \sum_p - \log(1-p^{-1}) \\
 & {} = \sum_p \left( \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{2p^2} + \frac{1}{3p^3} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_{p}\frac{1}{p} \right) + \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3p} + \frac{1}{4p^2} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} < \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + \sum_p \frac{1}{p^2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \cdots \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \right) \\
 & {} = \left( \sum_p \frac{1}{p} \right) + C
\end{align}$$

for a fixed constant $C<1.$ Since the harmonic series diverges, the sum of the reciprocals of the prime numbers diverges.

Answer (score 3):

This is an overkill, but since

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n \ln(n)}$$

is divergent, it follows from the Prime Number Theorem that your series is divergent....

Now the question is: is the PNT considered an elemenatry tool? ;)