# Divergent series of $\frac{1}{P_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

the series of terms $\frac{1}{P_n}$, where $P_n$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number, is divergent, I know only one proof using logarithm, is there another proof?

Comment: Yes, there are several other proofs. Did you google this site? Look for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523272/proof-of-divergence-of-1-2-1-3-1-5-1-7-1-11?noredirect=1&lq=1). Also, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) offers several proofs.

Comment: If you look for a really elementary proof, look at Paul Erdős' proof which is given in the Wikipedia article linked by Dietrich Burde. As Steve Irwin would've said: She's a beauty.

Comment: proof using only logarithm? Could you be more precise?

Comment: @clark i will share this proof on the other feed as this one is closed as duplicate