# Prove of divergence of reciprocals of primes without infinitude of primes.

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof, distribution-of-primes

I read in a text that Euler once proved the infinitude of primes by proving the divergence of their reciprocals, which seems to me a highly pleasing. However, I am only familiar with one proof of the primes' reciprocals' divergence and it *requires* the infinitude of the primes in one of its steps (it essentially compares the sum of primes cleverly with the harmonic series using some nice inequality manipulations).

I don't need to see Euler's original proof (which I am informed was insufficiently rigorous for my, modern, tastes anyway) but is there an elementary proof of the divergence of primes' reciprocals that *does not* require the infinitude of the primes?

Comment: One cannot prove the divergence of reciprocals of primes without the infinitude of primes, because it would be convergent for only finitely many primes. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15946/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-converge) for a proof of the divergence.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think what Isky Mathews means is a proof of divergence of the reciprocals which does not rely on a prior proof of infinitude. Of course divergence of reciprocals would imply infinitude.

Comment: @Y.Forman: Thank you - this is precisely what I mean.

Comment: The proof does not rely on that, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523272/proof-of-divergence-of-1-2-1-3-1-5-1-7-1-11?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I think (perhaps a modernized version of) Euler's proof had to do with the fact that the Zeta function has a pole at $1$, and $\log \zeta(s)$ can be identified with $\sum \frac1{p^s}$, so the fact that this diverges as $s \to 1$ proves the infinitude of the primes. I think this line of reasoning can be done rigorously. It relies on the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, but not on infinitude of the primes. I don't have a reference on me at the moment.

Comment: Just saw Dietrich Burde's comment. Basically what Dietrich Burde linked to.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes#Euler's_proof

Answer (score 0):

Euler said.

$\zeta(s) = 1 + 2^{-s} + 3^{-s}+4^{-s} + \cdots\\
2^{-s}\zeta(s) =  2^{-s} + 4^{-s} + 6^{-s} \cdots\\
(1-2^{-s})\zeta(s) = 1 + 3^{-s}+5^{-s} + \cdots\\
(1-2^{-s})(1-3^{-s})\zeta(s) = 1 + 5^{-s}+7^{-s} + 11^{-s} +\cdots$

This is effectively the sieve of Eranthoses

$\prod_\limits{p \text { prime}} (1-p^{-s})\zeta(s) = 1\\
\zeta(s) = \prod_\limits{p \text { prime}} \frac {p^s}{p^s-1}\\
\zeta(1) = 1 + \frac 12 + \frac 13 + \frac 14 + \cdots = \infty\\
\prod_\limits{p \text { prime}} \frac {p}{p-1} = \infty$

If the set of prime numbers were finite, then the left hand side would be finite, but as it isn't it ain't